# Parabolas Inequalaties

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

If a vertical parabola opens upward, has its vertex in the third quadrant, and $y=ax^2+bx+c$ is the equation of this parabola, which of the following can be true? Sketch a curve for each possible case.

$a>0$, $b>0$, $c>2$

---

I think it could be both ways. I know $a$ and $b$ are $> 0$ but $c$ (or $y$-intercept ) could lie below the origin or above it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the parabola opens upwards forces $a>0$. The $x$-coordinate of the vertex of the parabola is $-\frac{b}{2a}$; since $a>0$ and this expression is negative, we have $b>0$ as well.

Finally, the $y$-coordinate of the vertex of the parabola is
$$a\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 = b\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right) + c = c-\frac{b^2}{4a}.$$
This expression must be less than zero. But this doesn't place much of a restriction on $c$. For example, $a=b=1$ implies that $c<\frac{1}{4}$, but it can be positive or negative. $a=1$ and $b=4$ implies that $c < 4$, so we could have $c>2$.

Comment: can c be less than 0?

Comment: Sure; since $a>0$ it is always true that $c-\frac{b^2}{4a}<0$ if $c<0$.